# Sockets - max size for send and receive buffers

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

For learning purpose I have created two simple C programms to simulate the following sockets scenario: a client in the loop sends 256 bytes to the server(`send` function with `MSG_DONTWAIT` flag) but the server doesn't read the data (`recv` function). For simplicity the server doesn't send any other data to the client. I would like to test when `send` method will return an error. I use linux `ss -nmtp` command to see what happens with socket buffers. First the server receive buffer (`Recv-Q`) and `skmem r` parameter is growing:

```
State  Recv-Q   Send-Q         Local Address:Port          Peer Address:Port 

ESTAB  768      0              127.0.0.1:9002              127.0.0.1:34246    users:(("tcpServer",pid=16455,fd=4))
skmem:(r2048,rb131072,t0,tb2626560,f2048,w0,o0,bl0,d0)

ESTAB  0        0              127.0.0.1:34246             127.0.0.1:9002     users:(("tcpClient",pid=16482,fd=3))
skmem:(r0,rb131072,t0,tb2626560,f0,w0,o0,bl0,d0)
```

When the server `Recv-Q` reaches value `98816` the client `Send-Q` and `skmem w` start growing. When the client send function returns the error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) the buffers sizes looks this way:

```
State  Recv-Q   Send-Q         Local Address:Port          Peer Address:Port

ESTAB  98816    0                  127.0.0.1:9002             127.0.0.1:49744    users:(("tcpServer",pid=21644,fd=4))
skmem:(r128256,rb131072,t0,tb2626560,f2816,w0,o0,bl0,d16)

ESTAB  0        2553798            127.0.0.1:49744            127.0.0.1:9002     users:(("tcpClient",pid=22042,fd=3))
skmem:(r0,rb131072,t0,tb2626560,f570,w2653638,o0,bl0,d0)
```

Does `skmem rb` refer to the max receive buffer size and `skmem tb` refer to the max send buffer size ? If so, how to explain difference between `Recv-Q` and `skmem rb` and `Send-Q` and `skmem tb`?

**Edit**

`skmem rb` is the same as the default size returned by the following command:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_rmem
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096    131072  6291456
```

but `skmem tb` is different than the default size returned by this command:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_wmem
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096    16384   4194304
```

How to explain it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of factors all coming together in your test. I'll try to walk through them. Much of this is documented in the man page for `ss` and `tcp`.

- Send-Q is the amount of memory currently devoted to buffering outbound data on that socket.
- Recv-Q is the amount currently buffering inbound data on that socket.
- Skmem r is the total allocated memory for received in-flight packets.
- Skmem w is the total allocated memory for sent in-flight packets.
- net.ipv4.tcp_mem contains the low, pressure, and high page count limits on memory for the TCP stack. The default page size is 4,096 so to arrive at bytes you will need to multiply these by the page size.

There are a lot of factors here, but ultimate the memory usage from all TCP sockets combined can not exceed tcp_mem's high setting. If you are currently exceeding the pressure setting, certain limitations may be imposed on connections that are memory heavy. In your case, this test would qualify for those.

This test isn't usually compatible with most real world scenarios, as applications will generally back off long before they receive **resource temporarily unavailable**.